# TCPDF method="write2DBarcode" tag not working in php 7.2

Tags: php, tcpdf, zend-framework3

It seems to me that

```
<TCPDF method="write2DBarcode" params="<?php echo $this->params; ?>"></TCPDF>
```

is not working in php 7.2. I just updated the php version to 7.2 and everything else is working except it is not showing the barcode written with this tag.

I also try the run their own example codes but they are not working either. The method `write2DBarcode` is working but not the tag used in HTML template.

Is it a php version issue or have i done something wrong?

Comment: I cannot see any example using that tag. All the examples I can find on their website (TCPDF) uses php code only. Is this some other library you are using on top of TCPDF that would make you expect that tag to work?

Comment: Here: https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_049/ Look closer.

Comment: Where did you put that? In your HTML or in the code that is used in the PDF? Provide us with a minimal and verifiable example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: I just ran the same example code and it is not showing the barcodes

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you updated TCPDF when you updated your PHP version.

Since version 6.2.0 of TCPDF, `K_TCPDF_CALLS_IN_HTML` is set to `false` by default. You'll need to set it to `true` in your TCPDF config file (see `config/tcpdf_config.php`) for example 49 to work.

Comment: My tcpdf version is 6.2.11 when i set that `K_TCPDF_CALLS_IN_HTML` to `true` i get Deprecated: each() error...

Comment: That issue was fixed in a later version, so you should update.